# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre módulo o resto de la división (%) y división (/) en C#?

Tags: c#, operador

Estoy empezando a programar en C# y me encontré con esta novedad, además de que me gustaría saber en qué casos se utiliza el módulo, lo agradecería bastante.

Comment: Hola Fernando bienvenido a esta tu familia de Programación jejeje, te invito a hacer el [tour] de la pagina para conocer bien como formular preguntas y como funciona el sitio, recordar algo importante antes de preguntar es necesario que investiguemos por nuestra parte, luego si no encontramos nada entendible preguntamos :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En C# (y en la mayoria de los lenguajes) el operador % (módulo) retorna el resto de realizar una división entera entre 2 números enteros, mientras que el operador / (división) retorna la división entre 2 numeros.

Por ejemplo:

- 5 % 2 retornará 1, ya que 5 / 2 = 2 con resto = 1
- 5 / 2 retornará 2, ya que 5 / 2 = 2

Answer (score 0):

Usando las operaciones de división " / " y de residuo " % " se puede obtener

```
int monto = 12345; //Monto a desglosar
int cantidad = 0;
int[] denominacionesMoneda = new int[] { 500, 200, 100, 50, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

Console.WriteLine("El desglose de $" + monto.ToString() + " es el siguiente:");
foreach(int moneda in denominacionesMoneda)
{
    cantidad = monto / moneda; //Obtiene el valor entero de la división
    monto = monto% moneda; //Obtiene el residuo de la división y lo considara como nuevo monto a desglosar
    Console.WriteLine(cantidad.ToString() + " billetes de $" + moneda);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]